# Class-to-class passing of data, optimization

Tags: php, oop, optimization

I have written a file-handler-class, that works like this:

- `__construct` *opens* and *ex-locks* a file, *reads* its json-content and *parses* that as an PHP-array, keeping this as a *property* of the class.
- The file is still locked, in order to avoid race-conditions.
- Other 'worker-classes' make changes in this Array, in/from other scopes.
- `__destruct` *encodes* the finished Array, *writes* it to file, and *unlocks* the file.

Everything works fine ...

**QUESTION**:

Is it sensible to keep the Array as a property of the original class, or is it better to pass the Array to the worker-classes, and let them return it at the end?

Perhaps there is a way to keep the Array locally, and pass it to worker-classes by reference, instead of as raw data?

I mean ... this is a question of not having duplicates, waisting memory. A question of speed, not passing things unnecessarily. And a question of best practices, keeping things easy to understand.

Comment: This is essentially the debate on dependency injection vs inheritance no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, by passing the array to another function, having that function modify the array, and then return it to some other caller that may or may not also conduct modifications on it, you are in fact copying that array multiple times (*since this invokes copy-on-write semantics in PHP*) and by definition wasting memory.

Whereas by keeping it as a property of the object instance, you would not be invoking any copy-on-write semantics, even if the caller is not the same instance. Since passing an object instance won't copy the array, nor will its modification from said instance.

Not to mention you just make it easier to retain state within that object (assuming you care about validation).

Comment: So to clarify. You are saying, that my approach of working on the array residing inside the file-handler-instance, is both sensible, fastest and best practice?

Comment: Yes, passing around an object instance, that contains an array member, is much cheaper than passing around an array when you intend to modify that array from another caller. The reason is you force PHP to copy the array when you modify it from the local scope of a function, but if it lives inside the instance property, PHP will never copy it even if you modify it from some other scope.